# The composition of weakly compact operators and completely continuous operators

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be weakly compact and $S:Y\rightarrow Z$ be completely continuous. Clearly, the operator $ST$ is compact. My question is how to quantify this elementary fact.

Let us fix some notations. If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty subsets of a Banach space $X$, we set $$d(A,B)=\inf\{\|a-b\|:a\in A,b\in B\},$$$$\widehat{d}(A,B)=\sup\{d(a,B):a\in A\}.$$

Let $A$ be a bounded subset of a Banach space $X$. The Hausdorff measure of non-compactness of $A$ is defined by $\chi(A)=\inf\{\widehat{d}(A,F):F\subset X$ finite$\}$. Then $\chi(A)=0$ if and only if $A$ is relatively norm compact. The de Blasi measure of weak non-compactness of $A$ is defined by $\omega(A)=\inf\{\widehat{d}(A,K): K\subset X$ is weakly compact $\}.$ Then $\omega(A)=0$ if and only if $A$ is relatively weakly compact. For an operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$, $\omega(T), \chi(T)$ will denote $\omega(TB_{X}),\chi(TB_{X})$ respectively. For a bounded sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in $X$, we set $ca((x_{n})_{n})=\inf\limits_{n}\sup\limits_{k,l\geq n}\|x_{k}-x_{l}\|.$ Then $(x_{n})_{n}$ is norm Cauchy if and only if $ca((x_{n})_{n})=0$. For an operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$, we set $cc(T)=\sup\{ca((Tx_{n})_{n}):(x_{n})_{n}$ weakly Cauchy in $B_{X}\}$. Clearly, $T$ is completely continuous if and only if $cc(T)=0$.

Question. Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be an operator and $S:Y\rightarrow Z$ be an operator. Then $\chi(ST)\leq C\cdot\max(\omega(T),cc(S)),$ where $C$ is a universal constant?

Thank you!

Comment: May I ask what is the main motivation behind this?

Comment: @TomekKania  As you said, an operator with range $L_{1}$ is weakly compact if and only if it is strictly cosingular. This result is due to Pelczynski. The main motivation behind my question is to give a quantitative version of Pelczynski's result.